# How loud can an induction hob be?

Tags: electrical-engineering, acoustics, noise

People that are cooking food with induction will occassionally encounter loud noises from the hob. There can occur a high-pitched whining sound when heating the pots and/or pan. As I searched the internet, there where no data on how high the noise level of induction hobs can be. Mostly it is silent, but occassionally the noise level can be very high in my own experience. What is the peak noise intensity that an induction hob can achieve (and maybe why)?

Comment: I get to hear cooling fans or the sounds of boiling or frying.

Comment: This is far too broad.  You'd need to identify model numbers,  the exact cookware in use, and most definitely a spectral dB meter before making any such claims.